# Distribution of minimum of uniform vector on n-sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, geometric-probability

I'm working on an economic model with a nonlinear production network, and part of the model ends up being described by $\min_i(X_i)$ (the smallest component of $X$), where $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector uniformly distributed on the sphere $||X||_2=1$. Is there a known formula for the distribution of $\min_i(X_i)$?

If it's easier, I'd also be interested in any possible solution for alternative $L_p$ norms, e.g. the restriction that $||X||_1=1$.

I'd actually ideally like to be able to calculate some moments of $\min_i(X_i)$, such as $\mathbb{E}[|\min_i(X_i)|^\alpha \mid \min_i(X_i)<0]$ for some $\alpha$, but I suspect that will be a bit too difficult.

An alternative possibility would be to take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and use extreme value theory.

Comment: First, the notation $\min(X)$ is confusing. Do you mean $\min_i(X_i)$ (the smallest component?) Or perhaps $\min_i(|X_i|)$ ?

Comment: Further, by $n-$sphere you mean $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n = 1$ or  $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n \le 1$ ? (usually, a $n-$sphere lives in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere )

Comment: Both great points, I've updated the question to clarify. I also generalized it a bit, to give more possibilities for an answer.

Comment: Sorry but : are you sure you don't mean $|X_i|$ ? (or elswhere aren't you restricting to positive values?). For one thing, $(X_i)^\alpha$ would be problematic for negative values.

Comment: Yes, thank you again. I'm impressed you read that far through the question.